# Block browser tabs using jquery

Tags: jquery, browser

Is there a way to block browser tabs using jquery? or atleast is there a way to create a script that will work in all browser tab at once. Deal is I have a form that can be send multiple times and that's is right thing, and he can be opened in multiple tabs in my browser. I want to create some sort of blockade that will stop moving to other tabs or submitting other forms until one is done sending, and it seems I cant find a way to do it.

Comment: Really broad question, but it can be done with javascript. But you have to make your question more specific and share your code you have tried so far.

Comment: JavaScript can not do cross-tab scripting in the browser (it is a security risk). If the 2nd tab was opened using window.open(), and the browsers settings were set up such that new popup windows open in a new tab instead, then tab1 can communicate with tab2

Comment: No, but it can make an ajax call and for example prevent the form being submitted, or tell the user you have something that is not finished in the other tab.

Comment: I think there are no way@!

Comment: You would have to deal with that server side where the form is being submitted.  Only let one "client" through at a time and randomly generate a client id when the form is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **HTML5 Local Storage:**

```
    $(function () {
        var formLoadCount = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("FormLoadCount") || 0);
        if (formLoadCount == 0) {
            alert("form is successfully loaded");
        }
        else {
            alert("form is already loaded in another tab");
        }
        formLoadCount = parseInt(formLoadCount) + 1;
        localStorage.setItem("FormLoadCount", formLoadCount);

        $(window).unload(function () {
            formLoadCount = formLoadCount - 1;
            localStorage.setItem("FormLoadCount", formLoadCount);
        });
    });
```